# displaying the robot's actual trajectory in RViz

Tags: navigation, rviz, move-base, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a mobile robot which is navigating around a room, I already have the map of the room. I am using rotary encoders for odometry. I am fusing the data from Rotary encoders and IMU using [robot_pose_ekf](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_pose_ekf). I am using [amcl](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl?distro=jade) for localization and [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base?distro=jade) for planning with SBPL Lattice Planner as the global planner and Trajectory Planner as the local planner.
Now when I run RViz, I can visualize the global plan (desired trajectory) generated by move_base but I would also like to visualize the actual trajectory (based on odometry data and amcl) followed by the robot in RViz. I want to do this so that I can see how much is the actual trajectory different from the desired trajectory. Is there any package in ROS which does this (I am not able to find any such package)? If not, what is the best way to visualize the robot's actual trajectory in RViz? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213157/displaying-the-robot%27s-actual-trajectory-in-rviz/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[hector_trajectory_server](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_trajectory_server) does what you request. See also this other older [Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/171771/rviz-trace-robot-path/).  :)

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-07-13**:
Thanks @Stefan! It worked like a charm :)

**Comment by [rosRabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23646/rosrabbit/) on 2015-09-08**:
works for me too. Thanks for sharing!

**Comment by [peigong](https://answers.ros.org/users/31721/peigong/) on 2017-08-31**:
Could you give me some guidance on how to use this node (or Tutorial on using this node)?@Stefan

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Visualize the odometry in rviz with history?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-07-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosRabbit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23646/rosrabbit/) on 2015-09-08**:
This method could work when odometry information is published. But sometimes, there is no such topic. So we have to use other method. The above method could work!